# How BLE 4.2 streming is working

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I cannot understand how BLE 4.2 headphones are working.
As I know, with BLE protocol you can send 20 bytes only in each packet, so normal listening quality is not possible in this case.
Somebody knows the correct answer?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headsets running Bluetooth 4.2 spec doesn’t run audio via the BLE links. This is a quite common misunderstanding, but for streaming music and making phone calls etc all phones and computer as of today still use the Bluetooth 2.1 spec and what’s called “classic” profiles to do the work (eg., A2DP for music, HFP for voice calls, etc).

There are indeed streaming audio profiles for GATT/BLE in the making but nothing that’s available yet and consequently not anything that’s supported by products available today.

It’s quite common to see headsets that claim superior audio quality etc “because we use the latest Bluetooth 4.2 spec”. :) The only reason that the product IS indeed listed/qualified as a 4.2 or 5.0 spec is because you typically always qualify your products using the latest spec — but that’s doesn’t imply that the product USE all the latest bits and pieces in that spec...

Comment: Very interesting issue!
Could you please provide me some materials/links/documents about the algorithm for using the data transfer in normal time through the bluetooth (50-70Mbytes of files)? I'll very appreciate it! :)

Comment: I’m sorry @MichaelVaysman but I don’t really follow... what has transfer of 50-70Mbyte files got to do with how streaming audio to a headset...? :) If you are looking for how to send big data chunks via Bluetooth from A to B using classic Bluetooth or BLE, that’s obviously something that we can talk about further but perhaps that’s a different question here on SO?

Comment: I don't think that it's a different question. I need to transfer the data as quick as possible and I think that streaming, because of quality of the sound (aka big files) it's a great example. Am I wrong? :) For now I'm searching for all information about the quick transfer and about the proper way to do it.

Comment: Ok. Well, streaming of audio using the classic link A2DP is in itself built for the purpose of delivering encoded audio packets from a source (phone) to a sink (headset), and can’t be used for sending files as such. On-the-fly audio only, encoded by the source, sent via Bluetooth, and then decided by the sink. Transferring files can be done using OBEX or FTP profiles for classic links (depending on phone-support), or by using BLE to tunnel a “chunk by chunk” approach that eventually will deliver the full data. However, keep in mind that using BLE for this purpose will take x hours...

Comment: Essentially, what I’m trying to say is that A2DP cannot be used for what you need. Instead in opt for other classic links m as I mentioned, possibly also a raw SPP-link from Android but it all comes down to what you want to do with the file on the phone/headset side I guess. I would honestly avoid trying to send 50-70MB of data over BLE as you’d face transfer times of approx 30+ hours, possibly more... a typical “over-the-air” FW upgrade of a headset transfers ~750kB of data and takes anywhere from 30 to 60 minutes depending on phone-support.

Comment: If your use-case does require iOS support, I’d recommend joining the MFi program to get access to Apple’s iAP classic links which do allow you to send raw data since OBEX and FTP profiles as not supported unless you jailbreak the phone.

Comment: really, really thank you for your help!! What can you say about BLE5 ? It's the same files transfer speed as at version 4, or can be more quick? By the way, if you could post here some useful links - I'll very appreciate it! :)

Comment: @MichaelVaysman, the Bluetooth 5 specification is an extension for LE to improve as a suitable technology for Internet-of-Things applications. You can increase range OR throughout, not both. Hence, an over-the-air upgrade of FW can be done quicker if that’s the use-case, or a sensor can reach further in other use-cases. Moreover, Bluetooth 5 offer a decentralized “mech-topology” allowing for multi-hop instead of the star-topology used until now. But again, all of these are optional additions to LE and *not* explicit just because a product claims Bluetooth 5 compliance.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Even though packets are small, the radio still operates at 1 Mbit/s when it actually sends/receives something. What you want to make sure is that the radio is active as much as possible with as low overhead as possible. With data length extension each packet can be up to 251 bytes instead of 27 bytes. And with several packets per connection event you can get very high throughput (over 800 kbit/s).

Comment: That’s not applicable to how streaming works on Bluetooth headsets today though. Audio streaming via BLE is not commercially available yet, nor do we know how it will integrate with existing classic profiles and their integration with Android/iOS etc.